# Android URLConnection read() Exception-Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am writing Android app to download specific file (currently 20M Byte) from a web site for test purposes. I use **URLConnection** and **BufferedInputStream**.
After downloading several Mega Bytes, I receive *IOException Connection Reset By Peer*.
The *inputStream.read()* halted for about 130sec, then the exception raised.
From several tries, I noticed that the downloaded bytes are either 11,272,192, or 11,010,048 knowing that the file can be downloaded normally from PC.
Following is the code snippet I used:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conection.setDoOutput(false);

            conection.connect();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            ...

            do {
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];;

                if (((count = input.read(data)) == -1)) {
                    break;
                }
                sum+=count;

            ...

            } while (true);
            input.close();
            conection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I want to know what causes this issue, and how to avoid it.
I read multiple (similar subject) issues, but non of them helped. They all agree that there is **nothing wrong with code** and **it is network (or host) issue**. But I need to know why the download failed and how to overcome it
knowing that

- I moved the same file to different host, with same issue
- The download never succeeded at different times

Comment: `data = new byte[dataCount];`. Are you creating an 11 MB buffer? For what? You only have one read() for 11MB? What are you going to do with that buffer afterwards? Isn't `input.available()` often delivering wrong values? Have you checkd if they are equal file size on server?

Comment: If you indeed can read `dataCount` bytes in one read() then you should break the loop if `count==dataCount`.

Comment: `there is nothing wrong with code`. Code just does not look fine.

Comment: I added input.available() lately, as a try, but no success.There is nothing wrong with code in general, but there is something make the download break.   I am not allocating 11MB buffer, but the download breaks on ~11MB. I updated the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: input.available() does not return filesize, but the cached (or fetched) bytes which is multiple of kbytes and no more 65k (noticed from debugging), but sometimes 0. So I removed it.

Comment: You have not given the info i asked for.

Comment: @greenapps _`Are you creating an 11 MB buffer?For what?`_  No, I am using 1k buffer _`You only have one read() for 11MB?`_ I am using while loop to read data 1kB at a time. loop will break if no data (`input.read(data)==-1`). _`What are you going to do with that buffer afterwards?`_ for now nothing, I just want check the _`read`_ issue. _`Isn't input.available() often delivering wrong values?`_ Yes, so I removed it._`Have you checkd if they are equal file size on server?`_ What do you mean?, the file in server is 20MB, while only 11MB is downloaded, then exception raised.

Answer (score 0):

Connection reset by peer error occurs when the server closes the connection by sending RST packet.There can be many reasons why server can do this - you could be using too much of resources so it may close the connection,there could be some error in the server configuration etc.I had this same error so I changed the buffer size from 1024 to 512 and it worked.I think it worked because this reduced the resources the server has to use.Also change input.read(data) to input.read(data,0,512).